# How to call a global dynamic variable in php

Tags: php, arrays, global-variables

I try to find the solution since many hours, but I can't solve it (I'm not a programmer ;)).

On a function, I have set a dynamic array which I want to use in another function.
To do this, I thought to use $GLOBALS[] array
I have no problem to call the variable out of the function one, but when I try to use it in function 2, it doesn't works.

Here is my code :

```
function one($name,$a,$b,$c)
{
// $GLOBALS[${$name}] = array($a,$b,$c);
global $$name;
$$name = array($a,$b,$c);
}



function two($name)
{
$name="D1";
echo ${$name}[1];
}

one("D1",10,20,30);
one("D2",100,200,300);
two("D1");      // doesn't works


$name="D1";
echo ${$name}[1];   // works, gives 20
$name="D2";
echo ${$name}[1];   // works, gives 200
```

It doesn't works and I do not understand why.
Thanks for your help.

Etienne

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: using `global $name;` could be easier

Comment: Dear Paul,
I tried your way, but I still have the same problem with the function two.

'function one($name,$a,$b,$c)
{
global $$name;
$$name = array($a,$b,$c);
}
function two($name)
{
echo ${$name}[1];
}
one("D1",10,20,30);
one("D2",100,200,300);
two("D1");  // doesn't works
$name="D1";
echo ${$name}[1]; // works, gives 20
$name="D2";
echo ${$name}[1]; // works, gives 200'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

function one($name,$a,$b,$c)
{
    global $$name;
    $$name = array($a,$b,$c);
}

function two($name)
{
    global $$name;
    echo ${$name}[0];
}

one("D1",10,20,30);
two("D1");
```

The scope of your function is different to the global scope.

Comment: Thank you very much Progrock !

Comment: I did not know that, I thought that the global scope was on all the document including all functions ! I would like to be sure to understand. To use the 'global' variable in another function, you need to declare it in the function using 'global'. I have just read again the french php user guide, I it written, but it was not so clear to me ;)   So thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

how about doing something like this:

```
function one() {
  $dynamicArray = generateDynamicArray();
  return $dynamicArray;
}

function two() {
  $one = one(); // if it's in a class use: $this->one();
  foreach($one in $key=>$value) {
       // your code for each item in the array we got form function one() 
  }
}
```

instead of defining it globally.

Comment: Dear Chandlerbing,
Thank you for your answer, but I'm not enough skilled to understand it.
I clarified my question, hope it will be more clear for you. thanks